# Hacer tipo fetchAll y while en mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo un sistema basado en membresías. Los datos principales de las membresías como lo son: id_paquete y fecha_vencimiento se guardan en la tabla "membresia" y los privilegios a afectar se guardan en la tabla membresia_privilegios con los campos: privilegio1, privilegio2, privilegio3,etc.

Estoy realizando un procedimiento almacenado que se ejecuta todos los días 
 periódicamente a las 23:59 a través de una tarea en el servidor mysql.

Entonces necesito hacer lo siguiente:

```
//Obtener el id de todas las empresas que vencen HOY
SET @empresas =  (SELECT * FROM membresia WHERE vencimiento < CURDATE());

//Recorrer los identificadores para efectar la tabla de privilegios de cada membresía.

WHILE() DO
END WHILE;
```

Esa es la idea que tengo para hacerlo, pero no logro pasar de la primera sentencia pues obtengo este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar a corregir la sentencia y a recorrer el while pues no tengo la más minima idea de como funcione.

Gracias de antemano.

**EDITADO**: 
He logrado obtener el ID de las empresas que han vencido. Tengo una variable tabla con esos identificadores. Ahora me toca recorrerlos. ¿Como es este proceso en mysl?

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS datos;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE datos(id int);
INSERT INTO datos(id) select id from membresia WHERE vencimiento < CURDATE();
select * from datos;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Explica mejor la pregunta, por ejemplo, ¿cómo se deben guardar los datos en la afectación (parece que fila por fila dado que intentas un bucle)? Pon un ejemplo de cómo sería la consulta que guarda los privilegios. ¿No se pueden guardar también en  una sola fila/columna separados por coma?

Comment: @A.Cedano guardar cualquier cosa separadas por coma "suele" ser una mala idea

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo @gbianchi, preguntaba para que se aclare un poco más el contexto.

Comment: igual, tener una tabla que diga privilegio1, privilegio2, etc tambien es una mala idea... hay que tener una tabla de privilegios...

Comment: @gbianchi al menos por la convención de nombres, la tabla `membresia_privilegios` sería una tabla asociativa que guardaría los identificadores de las tablas `membresia` y  `privilegios` que estarían en relación... falta contextualizar más la pregunta según creo.

Comment: Empecemos por lo primero no puedes poner select * debe ser select id y si son varios resultados entonces debes usar cursores, el error es que está mandando más de una columna al usar select *. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html

Comment: @gbianchi perdón la tabla contiene los campos, privilegio1, privilegio2, privilegio3, etc.

Comment: @A.Cedano efectivamente las tablas están relacionadas membresia_privilegios contiene un campo con un identificador llamada id_membresia.

Comment: Y cuando los privilegios sean 200 vas a tener 200 campos? y cuando sean 500? los vas a mandar a otra tabla.. la tabla privilegios debe tener un solo campo privilegio.. y tantos registros como privilegios tenga el usuario. dicho esto, el error es lo que te marcan por arriba por tratar de hacer select *

Comment: @Darkeniel OK, estoy de acuerdo contigo. Intenté crear una variable de tipo tabla y ahí guardar los resultados. como resultado tengo esto. Ahora creo que tengo que recorrer esa variable con un while:  https://prnt.sc/mbuh91 (Actualizo la pregunta)

Comment: Una variable de tipo tabla? Si quieres entender más el proceso puedes usar una tabla temporal pero al menos en este caso no lo veo necesario

Comment: @Darkeniel la verdad estoy súper liado con este tema y crear la variable tipo tabla hasta ahorita es lo que me ha resuelto lo que necesito que es: Obtener la lista de los id de las membresías ya vencidas. Es el inicio de todo. Ahora me toca recorrer esa tabla para ir actualizando los campos en la tabla membresia_privilegios.

Comment: Viste el enlace que te envié para recorrerlos?

Comment: @Darkeniel si, estoy intentando aplicarlo, pero es dificil porque es algo que desconozco, intento documentarme primero >.<

Comment: Primero se hace esto declaras el procedimiento luego declaras la variable de tipo cursor esta variable será la que recorrerás okay? Luego es tiempo que declares variables con las que trabajarás por ejemplo si el ID es tipo interesa debes declara una variable de tipo int Y así luego debes abrir el cursor Y hacer el fetch donde declaras la variable del cursor y harás into donde los valores de la consulta de cursor pasarán a la variable para que puedas trabajar con los datos Dentro de un look por ejemplo ahí podrás no se hacer un update tabla x where ID = variable con el ID

Comment: En el ejemplo de la documentación hay 2 cursores osea dos consultas ignora 1 y velo así, Honestamente te habría hecho el procedimiento pero ando desde el móvil hahaha

Comment: Neftalí, yo sigo dudando sobre tu modelo de datos al leer este comentario tuyo: *efectivamente las tablas están relacionadas membresia_privilegios contiene un campo con un identificador llamada id_membresia*  ... ¿Acaso la tabla no tiene también un campo `id_privilegio` y la relación debería ser *muchos a muchos*  expresada precisamente en esa tabla?

Comment: @A.Cedano Si, efectivamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terminé solucionándole de la siguiente manera:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS datos;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE datos(id INT);
INSERT INTO datos(id) select id from membresias WHERE vencimiento <= CURDATE();
SET @contador = (select count(*) FROM datos);


WHILE @contador > 0 DO

    /*Obtengo el primero id de la tabla temporal*/
    SET @identificador = (select id from datos  order by id LIMIT 1);

    /*Se actualizan los privilegios para cada membresia*/
    UPDATE membresia_privilegios SET privilegio1=1, privilegio2=1 WHERE id=@identificador;
     /*Se actualiza la membresia*/
    UPDATE membresias set paquete=1, vencimiento=NULL where id=@identificador;

    /*Se realizan otras configuraciones*/   


    /*Se eleimina el id que se actualizó para obtener el siguiente*/
    DELETE from datos where id=@identificador;
    SET @contador = (select count(*) FROM datos);
END WHILE;


END
```